# Refactoring global instances to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, global-variables

I am working on a CPP project that has a few global variables, for example:

```
class A;
class B;
A a;
B b;
```

I want to have the option of switching between different values of a and b. Ideally,
there shouldn't have been global variables at all or they should have been pointers
so that we could easily switch. E.g. If we have:

```
B* b; A* a;
```

then we can change a and b at run time. However, the problem is that the variables 
a and b are called hundreds of times in the project, and I would have to change
all those lines from

```
a.something
```

to

```
a->something
```

which might take a while. Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: I don't see an obvious way in which references would be helpful -- once you initialize a reference, you can't "re-seat" it to refer to a different object.

Comment: You could theoretically add references to the parameter lists of every function that uses those global variables (and to the parameter lists of every function above those in the call tree) and thread your globals through the program with references. Gets rid of the globals and keeps the `.` syntax, at the cost of changing a lot of function signatures.

Comment: Is there a quicker way to perform a global search and replace ? Um. is something wrong with performing a global-search-and-replace ??

Comment: Will have to change many function signatures and their calls, I think I'm better off doing a global search and replace. I was hoping I could avoid that and avoid debugging the resultant code. Thanks for the replies. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# clean checkout from version control
find . -name *.c -exec perl -i -pe 's/\<a\.(\w+)/a->\1/g' \{} \; 
# review changes, fix the places the regex got wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complicated A is...

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct D : public A {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "D\n"; }
};

struct Ref {
  void set(A* obj) { o = obj; }
  void print() { o->print(); }
  A* o;
};

Ref a;

int main() {
  a.set(new A());
  a.print();
  // switch a
  a.set(new D());
  a.print();
}
```

Comment: That is way too much work since A is really complicated. Did search and replace, worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: @turing_machine, Good.  Fixing it rather than pasting over it is a way better solution in the long run.